# Integrating Laravel and Elasticsearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

There are multiple packages to integrate elasticsearch with laravel.
Most of them providing an elegant query syntax: "eloquent style".
Because of elastic's unique query syntax there might be people looking for a 1:1 elastic query syntax being used by laravel. This improves testability -eg with ElasticSearch Head- and avoids translation errors to the eloquent like syntax (which translates it back to the original elastic query syntax anyway). Also while the Eloquent model is very strong in providing solutions for relational databases, elastic is a not a relational database, but a distributed search engine. 
So, how to start using elastic with laravel by using elastic's own json based query language and use the elastic queries 1:1 in laravel and become 100% elastic compatible?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Es\Search;

class Boot
{


    public function getAanbod($havenhouder)
    {

      { 
        $json = '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"havenurl.raw":"'. 
        $havenhouder .'"}}],"must_not":[],"should": 
        []}},"from":0,"size":10,"sort": 
        [],"aggs":{}}';

        $params = [
                'index' => 'havens',
                'type' => 'hisdata',
                'body' => $json
        ];

        $results = \Elasticsearch::search($params);            

        foreach ($results['hits']['hits'] as $result) {
                $aanbod[] = $result['_source'];
        }            
        return $aanbod;   
      }
   }
}
```

**app:**
Providers > Cviebrock\LaravelElasticsearch\ServiceProvider::class,
Aliases >   'Elasticsearch' => Cviebrock\LaravelElasticsearch\Facade::class,

**composer:**
require >   "cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch": "^2",

In this example a class is being created which can be called by using it's namespace. I prefer making it available to the service container by it's own contract. The $json property defines the query we are using for search and is identical to the json we serve elastic as a query. So if we're testing queries with Elastic eg. by means of ElasticSearch Head it's exactly the same query input. Aggregates etc.? No problem. 
Further more don't forget to composer dump-autoload on after installation and configure the elastic connection in .env.